# I want to know how many time I using "backspace" on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, keypress, keydown

In this **RichTextBox** I want to know how many times is used the **"Backspace" key** on keyboard. So far I have already used this code, but something is wrong. This is the scenario: when pressing Enter, a MessageBox will show how many times has the Backspace been used. Please help me..

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    Dim count As Integer

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Back) Then
        count = count + 1
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
        MessageBox.Show(count)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Like in [this question asked a couple of days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284811/vb-studio-timer-not-providing-output#comment91518342_52284811) it is simply a matter of scope. Every time `KeyDown` runs you declare a _**new**_ variable named `count`. Move the declaration to class-level, outside the event handler.

Comment: message box show "0"

Comment: When I try to running, message box just show "0"

Comment: You can try using the 'Static' keyword here:  `Static count As Integer`  This will cause the variable to retain its value between calls to the method.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Visual Vincent, you need move the declaration of 'count' out of the event.

```
   Private count As Integer = 0

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then count += 1

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            MessageBox.Show(count)
            count = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```